# RecyclerView is scrolling to the bottom of the view after loading items from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

How do I get the view to remain at the beginning of the list?

I have tried `scrollTo(0,0)` but it did not seem to work.

EDIT:
my recyclerview imp..

```
newsFeedView.setHasFixedSize(false);
newsFeedView.setLayoutManager(
    new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewsFeed, NewsFeedHolder> mAdapter;
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewsFeed, NewsFeedHolder>(NewsFeed.class,
    R.layout.item_newsfeed, NewsFeedHolder.class,
    database.child("posts").orderByChild("timeCreated")) {...}

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/detail_comments_view"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="295dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/details_cv"
  android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/comment_test_button"
  />
```

let me know if you need more

Comment: Consider adding some of your code so we can better help you...

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding some code that make recyclerview automatically scrolling?

Comment: yea im pretty sure all my calls to my rv have nothing to do with that

Answer (score 1):

I had to change

```
new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

and add

```
.setReverseLayout(true);
.setStackFromEnd(true);
```